# Shell: is there a way to remove the invisible characters in text file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, character-encoding

I am working on a speech recognition task and I have a large dataset of text files to be used in the task.

The text files were collected by a web app so I am assuming they were stored in utf-8 enocding.

for understanding let's take a file 50690.txt

in linux

when I do `cat 50690.txt` I see the following:

he�is�a�boy

--

when I do `vim 50690.txt` I see:

he| is| a| boy

--

expected:
he is a boy

*note: when I open the same file in vscode or any other editor I don't see the special characters on windows.

I have tried `sed`, `perl`, `dos2unix`

I have even created this shell script to remove the character but it has failed to remove them:

**remove_uglies.sh**

```
fname=${1}

cmd="cat ${fname} \
    | sed 's/[0-9][0-9]*/ & /g'  \
    | sed 's/ ء / /g' \
    | sed 's/\// /g' \
    | sed 's/‘/ /g' \
    | sed 's/’/ /g' \
    | sed 's/،/ /g' \
    | sed 's/“/ /g' \
    | sed 's/”/ /g' \
    | sed 's/ﷺ/ /g' \
    | sed 's/-/ /g' \
    | sed 's/ٴ/ /g' \
    | sed 's/:/ /g' \
    | sed 's/\./ /g' \
    | sed 's/؟/ /g' \
    | sed 's/!/ /g' \
    | sed \"s/'/ /g\" \
    | sed 's/\؛/ /g' \
    | sed 's/)/ /g' \
    | sed 's/(/ /g' \
    | sed 's/%/ /g' \
    | sed 's/\^/ /g' \
    > ${fname}1 "
#echo $cmd
eval $cmd

cmd="cat ${fname}1 \
    | sed 's/\xd9\x8f//g' \
    | sed 's/\xd9\x91//g' \
    | sed 's/\xd9\x92//g' \
    | sed 's/\xd9\x8e//g' \
    | sed 's/\xd9\x90//g' \
    | sed 's/\xd9\xb0//g' \
    | sed 's/\xd9\x8b//g' \
    | sed 's/\xEF\xBB\xBF//' \
    | sed 's/\xd8\xa3/\xd8\xa7/g' \
    > ${fname}2 "
#echo $cmd
eval $cmd

cmd="cat ${fname}2 \
 | sed  's/hazaar/ /g' \
 | sed  's/ 000/ /g' \
 | sed  's/ 00/ /g' \
 | sed  's/ 0/ /g' \
 | sed  's/saou/ /g' \
 | sed  's/ 00/ /g' \
 | sed  's/ 0/ /g' \
 | sed  's/|/ /g' \
 | sed  's/| / /g' \
 | sed  's/�/ /g' \
 | sed  's/ |/ /g' \
    > ${fname}3 "
#echo $cmd
eval $cmd

cmd="cat ${fname}3 \
 | tr '\n' ' ' \
 | perl -pe 's/\r/ /g' \
    > ${fname}4 "
#echo $cmd
eval $cmd

mv ${fname} ${fname}0
mv ${fname}4 ${fname}

rm ${fname}?
```

Comment: I have tried this:       
iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-8 -c file.txt
        
but this just removes the spaces as well

Comment: Your script is horribly broken for other reasons. `sed` allows you to combine multiple statements into a single script anyway. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still wandering, I was able to do this using iconv:

```
iconv -f windows-1252 -t ASCII//TRANSLIT -o OUTFILE.txt INFILE.txt
```

in my case :

```
    iconv -f windows-1252 -t ASCII//TRANSLIT -o 50690.txt 50690.txt
```

Comment: Converting to proper UTF-8 would probably break fewer things. You are basically wrecking any non-ASCII characters, which could be a serious problem if you need to process output in a language where e.g. diacricics are important (for example, the Swedish words _fan_, _fän_, and _fån_ all mean different things, and the one with the plain _a_ is mildly offensive).

Comment: the language I am working on is a spoken language without any  writing system so currently I have decided to not use any diacritics. The alphabet I have created for the language is still in development. I will keep your point in mind. Thank you so much

Comment: If the ASCII repertoire is sufficient, that's probably a good choice as such. Some languages have  reused otherwise unused letters like x, q, c, etc for sounds which do not have a letter in the regular alphabet (and I believe some use punctuation, too; e.g. `!` for a particular click sound in some south African languages). Allegedly the X in "Mexico" originally stood for a sound which the conquistadors could not figure out how to represent when writing home about it.